# How to show/hide elements depending on screen orientation in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use plain JS to detect the screen orientation of the device, but I have no clue how to show or hide elements depentend on the orientation. Basically the same as with [Ionic V2: HideWhen](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/show-hide-when/HideWhen/)

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic',
    'ngCordova',
    ....
])
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $rootScope, $state) {

    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

        ...

        window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {

            switch(window.orientation) {  
                case -90: case 90:
                    // landscape
                    // how to get this into the controllers scope?
                    break;
                default:
                    // portrait
                    // how to get this into the controllers scope?
                    break;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thats an excerpt of the template

```
<img class="cover" ng-src="http://i.imgur.com/vkW3Lhe.jpg" ng-show="orientation.landscape">
<img class="cover" ng-src="http://i.imgur.com/vkW3Lhe.jpg" ng-show="orientation.portrait">
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you ["bring it back to Angular land"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) with [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), `$apply`, etc...

```
angular.module('starter', [
    'ionic',
    'ngCordova'
])
    .factory('Orientation', function($ionicPlatform, $timeout){
        var ret = {
            LANDSCAPE: 'LANDSCAPE',
            PORTRAIT: 'PORTRAIT',
            current: void 0
        };

        function handleOrientation() {
            var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
            var isAndroid = ua.indexOf("android") > -1; // Detect Android devices
            if (isAndroid) {
                //window.orientation is different for iOS and Android
                if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) { //Landscape Mode
                    $timeout(function(){
                        ret.current = ret.LANDSCAPE;
                    })
                }
                else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) { //Portrait Mode
                    $timeout(function(){
                        ret.current = ret.PORTRAIT;
                    })
                }
            }
            else {
                if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) { //Landscape Mode
                    $timeout(function(){
                        ret.current = ret.LANDSCAPE;
                    })
                }
                else if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) { //Portrait Mode
                    $timeout(function(){
                        ret.current = ret.PORTRAIT;
                    })
                }
            }
        }

        $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
            window.addEventListener("orientationchange", handleOrientation);
            window.addEventListener("load", handleOrientation);
        })

        return ret;

    })
.controller('SomeController', function(Orientation, $scope) {
        $scope.$watch(
            function(){
                return Orientation.current; 
            },
            function(orientation){
                if(orientation === Orientation.LANDSCAPE) {

                }
                if(orientation === Orientation.PORTRAIT) {

                }
            })
    })
```

Comment: This is an untested quick answer and should be refactored with `$window` et. al.